# Sparsity Bounds for Probabilistic Polynomials

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, circuit-complexity, polynomials

Has there been any research done on proving sparsity lower bounds for probabilistic polynomials (over the Reals) for Majority?

A probabilistic polynomial is a distribution of polynomials $D$ such that for any $x$ and some  parameter $\epsilon$,

$Pr_{p \sim D}[p(x) = Maj(x)] > 1-\epsilon.$

And $p$ doesn't have to give a boolean output on the input it makes a mistake on.

To give some context, there are $\Theta(\sqrt n)$ probabilistic degree  bounds for Majority and Parity.

However the proofs of the lower bounds fail in the context of sparsity. Note Parity can be computed by a polynomial with sparsity 1 and degree $n$, when we consider inputs over $\{-1,1\}$.

A related notion is Polynomial Threshold Function (which is a function that outputs the sign of a real polynomial). There is a linear (and hence sparse) PTF that computes Majority (simply take $\sum_i x_i$). For parity, the same linear PTF can approximate with error $\sim 1/\sqrt n$.

So my question is can we leverage the fact that most outputs will be boolean in a probabilistic polynomial to derive any sparsity lower bounds for functions that are far from any sparse boolean function, like Majority?

Comment: Indeed we did some research a few years ago, and got what I thought were interesting results... but we were unable to publish in a conference. So we put the work aside and haven't returned to it yet. The main difficulty is that, unlike degree, the sparsity can depend very much on the basis (the elements you use for true and for false) as you note. We were able to show some fairly strong sparsity lower bounds for computing AC0 functions with {0,a} where a != 0, but not as much for {1,-1} in comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the response, that sounds fascinating! Would it be possible to take a look at those results? If so, I can email you (or whatever you prefer).

Comment: Sure feel free to email me, rrw@mit

Comment: emailed! thanks